# where the statictext is populating in richtextarea for custom object

Tags: apex, administration, page-layout, leads

I have leadtype as picklist .when value in the picklist is changing the static text is populating from richtext field called 'A' in object . In 'A' there is some static text with html is showingup. i am not able to find where that static text is populating from.
It is standard page and this field is displayed as section in layout. i tried to see in the layout also but not visible

when i wrote a query calleed

listdemo = [select id ,A from object__c];.

it is displaying the static text.

can someone guide me through this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming A is a text field when setting up a field you have an option to enter default value

[image]

Comment: but my text is changing when leadtype that is when picklist value changes. after save of record

Comment: did you check triggers/field update workflows. Easiest way to debug is this go to one of you sandbox, create a formula field and reference the text field in your formula, this is to ensure that there is atleast 1 place where this field is used. Delete the original text field that gets populated, salesforce will not allow you to delete the field and show you all places where the field is used.

Comment: Its is richtextarea field.when trying to create formula it is not showing up in merge field

Comment: uhhh can you create an empty class and just put a query with the field reference? The basic idea is to delete the field and get all the field references unless you want to install 3rd party apps to do the job of finding all the place where the field is referenced